# Compare between median/IQR and reference mean/SD

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, data-transformation, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have a small set of non-normally distributed measurement data (Kolmogorov-Smirnov rejected similarity to a normal distribution) and a reference value from a large population (n=120) of healthy individuals.

From the measurement data I have calculated the median and interquartile ranges. The reference values are however of a different nature: I have either the absolute limits of the reference (minimum and maximum of a large healthy population), or a mean and standard-deviation. There are 8 parameters, of which 4 reference values are given as a minimum and maximum over 120 healhty individuals. The other 4 reference values are given as a mean with standard-deviation.

I have searched for a good method to test whether the measurement data are significantly different than the reference data, but the difference in distributions is giving me some trouble.

A normal T-test assumes normal distribution, and therefore expects mean values. Mann-Whitney does not assume normal distribution, but does assume similar equal variance/shape, which also is not the case.

How then do I compare between two different distributions? Could I somehow transform/normalize/skew the measurement data? Should I construct a dummy set from the reference mean and SD, and transform this?